# Is there a way to get a list of all the Developers in App Store Connect?

Tags: app-store-connect, react-table

**Question:** Is there a way (without having to cut and paste row by row) to generate a list of developer ids from the App Store Connect Users And Access table? It's not an HTML table.

I also need device ids from a similarly problematic 'table'.

**What I've tried:**

1. Select all the values, then copy and paste them into Notepad. It doesn't get all the values. If I copy and paste a few rows at a time, this works, but it gets all the information across the whole row (not just the Apple Id that I need, so I have to manually remove all the extra data for 60+ rows), is error prone and time consuming (there are more than 60 developers and over 100 devices on a separate table).
2. Chrome browser extension 'ColumnCopy'. It doesn't work because it's not an html table.
3. Inspecting the code and copying from there. Can't get that to work.
4. Asking Apple Support to generate a report of the Apple Ids for me. They won't.

**Screenshot of one of the tables I need:**

[image: Users and Access table]

Comment: You should be able to get it with AppStoreConnect API. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/list_users